# read dotted string inside single quote in PHP

Tags: php, regex, scanf

In PHP I'm trying to strip information and store them in $sysver variable from a string named $freply like this:

```
var id='E8ABFA19FDE2';
var sys_ver='17.37.2.49';
var app_ver='20.9.1.150';
```

using PHP **sscanf** with whe following parameters:

```
sscanf($freply, "var sys_ver='%[^']'", $sysver);
```

However a **blank result** in $sysver is all I get.

***UPDATE***
Working on the first row with:

```
sscanf($freply, "var id=' %[^']'", $ea);
```

Gives me a correct result loaded as expected in $ea, that shows E8ABFA19FDE2.
Someone is able to tell me where's the mistake?
Despite I'm using PHP I guess this question is related to Javascript too or any other C-like language.

Comment: In scanf, the expression %[chars] reads the longest string that contains the characters (or character ranges) in the bracket. A caret as first character reverses this: %[^chars] reads the longest string that does not contain any of the characters. Hence, %[^ ] reads stuff up to the next space, and %[^\n] reads stuff up to the next new line. In this case, where the string is delimited by single quotes, I should read the opening quote, then stuff up to the next quote and finally the closing quote: " '%[^']'". This format starts with a space and so discards white space before the first quote.

Comment: why don't you use preg_match?

Comment: @rajesh ujade, I guess I'll have the same result as in both cases we're dealing with a mistake I did with regular expression string. I'm just getting crazy to understand where is my fault. Because it's my fault for sure. This function exist and works since years.

Comment: Are you sure sscanf can take character groups as a parameter (like regexp)? it looks like you need to change it to `var sys_ver='%s'`. or just use preg_match with a real regular expression.

Comment: `sscanf()`'s format argument never needs a quantifier.  Please do not mislead researchers with your commented solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're telling `sscanf()` is your string is formatted beginning with the literal characters `var sys_ver...` etc. then you're passing it a string that starts with `var id...` and it's NOPE'ing right out.

This works:

```
sscanf($freply, "var id='E8ABFA19FDE2';\nvar sys_ver='%[^']'", $sysver);
```

or this:

```
foreach (explode("\n", $freply) as $line) {
    if (sscanf($line, "var sys_ver='%[^']'", $sysver)) break;
}
```

---

But really `sscanf()` is not quite the right tool for this job. Just use `preg_match()`:

```
preg_match("/var sys_ver='([^']+)'/", $freply, $matches);
$sysver = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Yeah! You're right! the last one is the best way to do it (using preg_match). But the previous one cleared me the mistake. I've tried to scan the entire block and that's wrong, splitting it in rows as you suggested, solved the problem. But I'll apply the preg_match for production. Thanks!